# In Exact Target SQL query for records added the previous day

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

In Exact Target I am trying to query the _Subscribers Data View to return the email addresses of everyone that was added to the list for the previous day.

Here's what I started with:

SELECT EmailAddress

FROM _Subscribers

WHERE ListName = 'myList' AND
    DateJoined = DATE_SUB(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND
    Status = 'Active'

But NOW() and CURDATE() aren't supported in ET. I'm not sure what else to use.

Answer (score 3):

Or...

SELECT EmailAddress
FROM _Subscribers
WHERE ListName = 'myList'
    AND **DateDiff(day,DateJoined,GetDate()) = 1**

Comment: Great! That's working-thanks @edu8rdo!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use GETDATE(), which is the SQL Server version of this.  Hope this helps.

Comment: The question was what to use instead of NOW() and CURDATE() which I answered, GETDATE().  That should not be a down vote, it's a legitimate answer.